# awk: create a table from a file

Tags: awk

I have a commandlog file and I want to select some info in a table format. The input is like this:

```
####################################################################################################
# Starting pipeline at Mon Jul 29 12:22:56 CEST 2013
# Input files:  test.fastq
# Output Log:  .bpipe/logs/27790.log
# Stage Results
mkdir ./QC_graphics_results/


####################################################################################################
# Starting pipeline at Mon Jul 29 12:22:57 CEST 2013
# Input files:  test.fastq
# Output Log:  .bpipe/logs/27790.log
# Stage Statistics_graph_2
 fastqc test.fastq -o ./QC_graphics_results/
mv .QC_graphics_results/*fastqc .QC_graphics_results/fastqc


####################################################################################################
# Starting pipeline at Mon Jul 29 12:24:18 CEST 2013
# Input files:  test.fastq
# Output Log:  .bpipe/logs/27790.log
# Stage GC_content [all]
# Stage Dinucleotide_odds [all]
# Stage Sequence_duplication [all]
prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.Dinucleotide_odds.gd -graph_stats dn -out_good null -out_bad null 
prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.Sequence_duplication.gd -graph_stats da -out_good null -out_bad null
prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.GC_content.gd -graph_stats gc -out_good null -out_bad null
```

The desired output would be a table with each stage and the command, like this:

```
    Stage result              mkdir./QC_grahics_results/
Stage Statistics_graph_2      fastqc test.fastq -o ./QC_graphics_results/
Stage GC_content [all]        prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.GC_content.gd -graph_stats gc -out_good null -out_bad null
Dinucleotide_odds [all]       prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.Sequence_duplication.gd -graph_stats da -out_good null -out_bad null
Stage Sequence_duplication [all]      prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.GC_content.gd -graph_stats gc -out_good null -out_bad null
```

I have been trying with AWK using the following code but I doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
 cat commandlog.txt | awk '/^#\ Stage*/{print $0} !/^#.*/{print $0}' | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^#*/){ if (b=1){next} else {a=$0 b=1 next;} else { if (NF!=0){func=$0 b=0 print $a\t$func\n}}' > ./statistic_files/user_options
```

Comment: The last set of stage results has three stages, and the results are in randomly different order. Please post a full expected result, with expected variations. I have it almost working for you.

Comment: @Anil the last set it would be great to merge the name of stage with the name of -graph_data parameter, or instead, merge the three commands in one uniq stage name.

Comment: Like @Anil said, the first two records are trivial but it seems there is no structure to the last record so I'm sure whatever answer is posted you will have some compliant that is doesn't work for you actual file ect ect.. without a description of the transformation or structure then I voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this in a file named awk0.

```
NF == 0                                {next}

substr($1,1,1) == "#" && $2 != "Stage" {next}

$2 == "Stage" && NF == 3               {stage_name = $2 " " $3
                                        next }

stage_name != ""                       {print stage_name, $0
                                        stage_name = ""
                                        next}

$2 == "Stage"                          {arr[$3] = ""
                                        next}

                                      {
                                        {for (i in arr) {
                                           if (match($0, i) != 0)
                                             print "Stage", i, $0
                                                        };
                                         }
                                       }
```

Then run with:
`cat commandlog.txt | awk -f awk0 > ./statistic_files/user_options`

Output:

```
Stage Results mkdir ./QC_graphics_results/
Stage Statistics_graph_2  fastqc test.fastq -o ./QC_graphics_results/
Stage Dinucleotide_odds  prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.Dinucleotide_odds.gd -graph_stats dn -out_good null -out_bad null 
Stage Sequence_duplication  prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.Sequence_duplication.gd -graph_stats da -out_good null -out_bad null
Stage GC_content  prinseq-lite.pl -fastq test.fastq -graph_data test.GC_content.gd -graph_stats
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the problem is weakly formalized for trivial solution with simple tools, try something like this in bash:

```bsh
for x in $(awk '/Stage /{print $3}' file.txt);
do
  g=`grep "test.$x.gd" file.txt`;
  test -z "$g" && g=`awk "/Stage ${x}/,/##/" file.txt | grep -v '#'`
  echo -e "Stage $x\t$g";
done
```

It will grab stage names (without spaces) from paragraph and then will try to map it with `-graph_data` parameter lines, if it won't find a match it will grab line between "stage name" declaration and next started pargraph (it is assumed that paragraph starts from `##` sequence). Should work.